# "Undefined symbols for architechture x86_64" using g++

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, g++, clang

I am compiling a simple "Hello world" program hw.cpp. It looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I am running on OS X. I compile with the following command:
`g++ hw.cp`
But receive an error message:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libc++.so, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x49 0x4E 0x50 0x55 0x54 0x28 0x6C 0x69 0x62 0x63 0x2B 0x2B 0x2E 0x73 0x6F 0x2E )
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
      std::__1::ctype<char> const& std::__1::use_facet<std::__1::ctype<char> >(std::__1::locale const&) in hw-a865c1.o
  "std::__1::ios_base::getloc() const", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::widen(char) const in hw-a865c1.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::basic_string(unsigned long, char) in hw-a865c1.o
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
      std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > std::__1::__pad_and_output<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::ostreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_tr
```

Which goes on like that until the last two lines:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What could be causing this error? I am most interested in understanding why this is happening.

Comment: This is the problem _"...ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libc++.so, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format..."_  How did you install/setup your tool-chain ?

Comment: [tag:g++] and [tag:clang] is an interesting tag combination, but certainly not in your case.

Comment: Do you have a compiler rigged for intel Macs and a library set for the newer ARM chips?

Comment: I have used homebrew. I have recently used `brew upgrade`. Is this what you mean by "tool-chain"? In response to user4581301, I am not sure. How could I see if this is the case? To clarify, I have an intel processor.

Comment: [Toolchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain). Groovy. The compiler and linker linker match the hardware. `0x49 0x4E 0x50 0x55 0x54 0x28 0x6C 0x69 0x62 0x63 0x2B 0x2B 0x2E 0x73 0x6F 0x2E` looks like ASCII text: *INPUT(libc++.so.* Recognizably English and references the name of a very common C++ library implementation. Doesn't mean much to me, but I'm no linker script Guru.

Comment: That stuff in /usr/local means you installed a compiler.  Haven’t found other compilers necessary except in rare cases on macOS. Try with AppleClang?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked

```
brew reinstall gcc
/usr/local/bin/g++-12 hw.cpp
```

I needed to specifically reference the GNU compiler and I also had to reinstall it beforehand.